# Windows Identity Foundation support stops, what does it mean?

Tags: c#, .net, wif

On the [products ending support in 2020 page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4470235/products-ending-support-in-2020) of Microsoft, it states that Windows Identity Foundation support will end on April 14, 2020.

What exactly won't be supported anymore? There is WIF 3.5 it was released as a separate runtime and SDK, which meant that every computer on which a WIF-enabled application ran had to have the WIF runtime installed. WIF 4.5 has been fully integrated into the .NET Framework.

We are currently using WIF 3.5 with classes in the following namespaces Microsoft.IdentityModel, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSFederation. Is it sufficient to upgrade this to WIF 4.5 with classes in the following namespaces System.IdentityModel, System.Security.Claims and System.IdentityModel.Services?

Comment: It's listed under Internet Explorer 10, but there is a WIF 3.5 and a 4.5. End of support is exactly what it sounds like: Use at your own peril, because stuff could break and you can't ask MS for help.

Comment: End of Support means it won't be fixed/patched anymore, and you won't receive any assistance from Microsoft if it breaks.  It doesn't mean they're going to remove it.